# Take values from one column and create new column from it

Tags: python, pandas

I have big database that has one column called "Measurments" and one column with called "data" which contains data about those different measurments, for example, i measurments you can find height, weight and different indices values and in data you will find the value for this "measurment".
I would like to organize this database in a way that each unique measurment type, will have its' own column, so for example i'll have column name weight, height ect. and the  vvalue they got from the column "data".

Until nowI have used this way in order to create many little databases with my relevant data:

```
df_NDVI=df[(df['Measurement'] == 'NDVI') & (df['Data']!='Corrupt')]
df_VPP_kg=df[(df['Measurement'] == 'WEIGHT')]
```

But as youcan see, it is not efficient and it creates many databases instead of one with those columns.

My end goal: to take each unique field from "measurments" column and create new column for  it with the correct data from column "data".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
df["obs"]=df.groupby("Measurements")["Measurements"].cumcount()
df.pivot(index="obs", columns="Measurements", values="Data")
```

So you will get 1 column for each unique value from `Measurements`, and `Data` will be order below by order of observation.